# Use memcache to store results from MySQL and perform later queries over them

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memcached

I have to run a recurrent task that needs to check over the last 3 months of posts and do some sql checks using activerecord. My performance is screwed as I need to do this task once per minute and some of my mysqls queries are slow.
I've been doing some tests with parallel, distributed and advance sql caching but on the meantime I'm wondering if I can just cache the results of the query into memcached and perform all later queries against this key.

```
@posts = Rails.cache.fetch('posts') { Post.where(updated_at: 3.months.ago..Time.now) }
```

And then:

```
@posts.where(some_query)
```

But the last instruction always goes to the database instead of using the memcached.

I will appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put your query into a static method with cache block like following:

```
def self.recent(query = nil)
  Rails.cache.fetch("post/#{ query || 'all' }") do 
   @posts = Post.where(updated_at: 3.months.ago..Time.now)
   @posts.where(query) if query.present?
 end 
end
```

Now use it somewhere else:

```
@posts = Post.recent('your query will go here')
```

It will preserve separate cache for separate query.